# Caracter ilegal en output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice, csv

Tengo una aplicacion que me exporta el resultado en un archivo .csv.

La exportacion realiza varios nombres de proyectos, uno de esos proyectos tiene en el nombre tag en HTML `<b>`.

Al tratar de crear este archivo, me sale un eror Ilegal character in path.

He tratado de poner en el resultado doble comillas:

```
"" + ProjectTitle + ""
```

Pero el error me sigue apareciendo.

Como podria evitar que me saliera este error y seguir la ejecucion de mi programa?

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: has comprobado que no tenga \n , \r , \t o alguna similar? Prueba a usar el arroba delante del string path tal que @"path" para un string literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando Linq, puedes limpiar todos los caracteres ilegales con una sola linea de codigo:

```
filename = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(filename, (current, c) => current.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty));
```

Comment: al tratar de incluir la solucion usando LINQ me aparece otro error (The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.)

Comment: Funciono finalmente!! muchas gracias, pude modificar el archivo final y ya me resulto. Mucho mas facil con  LIN!!

Comment: De nada,me alegro que te funcionara :)

Answer (score 1):

Los nombres de archivo tienen una serie de caracteres no permitidos. entre ellos los símbolos de mayor y menor que son usados para redirección.

Yo usaría [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx)
para limpiar los caracteres no permitidos a partir del nombre de proyecto.
Algo así:

```
string GetValidFileName(string projectTitle) {
  StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder();
  List<char> invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().ToList();
  for (int i = 0; i < projectTitle.Length; i++) {
    char c = projectTitle[i];
    if (invalidChars.Contains(c))
      fileName.Add('_');
    else
      fileName.Add(c);
  }
  return fileName.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error se genera porque existe muchos caracteres en los nombres de archivos que no son permitidos para fileName. Por esos los nombres de archivos en sistemas operativos como windows** Solo tienen caracteres A-Z, a-z, 0-9, espacios y en casos de no aplicar espacios usan guion bajo "_", o guion simple "-"

Puedes intentar una solución un poco mas simple que la anterior posteada.

`string fileName = "ProjectTitle";
foreach (char c in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
{
   fileName = fileName.Replace(c, '_');
}`

Este simple bucle encuentra caracteres invalidos en el filename y los remplaza por "_"

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo crear las rutas a archivos con el método Combine en lugar de concatenar cadenas:

```
rutaCompleta = Path.Combine(nombreCarpeta, Path.GetFileName(nombreArchivo.Replace("/","\\")));
```

[Método Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)

En esta página puedes ver mas métodos para el manejo de nombres de archivos y rutas (en inglés):

[Dotnet Perls Path](https://www.dotnetperls.com/path)